# Playframework Scala Specs2 JSON Matchers

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0, specs2

I'm using the Play! framework and trying to work with JSON response messages in Specs2 tests with no success.

What I am trying to do is assert key->value pairs in a JsValue like in the example below ... but I can't get the matchers to correctly pass.

```
import org.specs2.mutable._
import play.api.libs.json.{Json, JsValue}

class JsonSpec extends Specification {

  "Json Matcher" should {

    "Correctly match Name->Value pairs" in {
      val resultJson:JsValue = Json.parse("""{"name":"Yardies"}""")
      resultJson must  /("name" -> "Yardies")
    }

    "Correctly match Name->Value pairs with numbers as doubles" in {
      val resultJson:JsValue = Json.parse("""{"id":1}""")
      resultJson must  /("id" -> 1.0)
    }
  }
}
```

Errors I get are

```
{name : Yardies} doesn't contain '(name,Yardies)'
```

and

```
{id : 1.0} doesn't contain '(id,1.0)'
```

Not very helpful, I imagine that it is something simple I am missing (new to both Scala and Play)

Steve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `JsonMatchers` in specs2 should be tightened a little bit. They are `Matcher[Any]`, where `Any` is supposed to have a `toString` method which can be parsed by Scala's json parser (and not Play's one).

The following specification works as expected:

```
class JsonSpec extends Specification {

  "Json Matcher" should {

    "Correctly match Name->Value pairs" in {
      val resultJson = """{"name":"Yardies"}"""
      resultJson must  /("name" -> "Yardies")
    }

    "Correctly match Name->Value pairs with numbers as doubles" in {
      val resultJson = """{"id":1}"""
      resultJson must  /("id" -> 1.0)
    }
  }
}
```

In your case I suspect that parsing the `toString` representation of Play's Json values returns something slightly different what the matchers are expecting. This will be fixed in the next specs2 release.

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually trying to test the JSON responses from HTTP calls ... so I can just use the response content directly rather than converting it to a JsValue and it works fine.

Comment: In many cases invoking `toString` on the JsValue solves the problem. I've seen the same thing when using Spray Json and fixed it that way.